# Conditional manipulation of logical numbers

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

Please I have the following time series { 111110011111000000011000011111} in time interval of seconds. I want to use the following conditions on the sequence.
Assuming the logic (1) = True and (0) = false

if false occurs  < 3 seconds and are in between two "true" then it is translated as 1

For instance 11111001111
because the false occurs less than 3 times and is in between ones
the zeros is converted to 1. The answer is then
11111111111

if true is < 3 seconds they are translated into 0.
for instance, if the 0000001100000, since the ones occur less than 3 times then the answer becomes 0000000000000

The answer for the first example when the condition is applied is

11111111111100000000000011111

I will be grateful if anyone assists me in writing this code MATLAB
Thanks in advance

```
X = [1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1];  % Work with this array.
target = 3;
ind = find(X < target);
disp(ind);
logInd = X < target;
```

Comment: Is the input a string, or what is it exactly? Also, what have you tried?

Comment: So you are trying to deglitch by removing any pulses less than three seconds in length?  What if a short low pulse and a short high pulse are adjacent, which one should be removed?

Comment: Thanks for your response Luis, the input is logic arrays of 0 and 1  with a time sequence of 1 to 30. I have tried if loops and iteration but to no avail.  You help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: @Ben  I do not understand what you really mean by a low pulse and a short high pulse.  The condition is to change pulse that is less than 3 seconds to 1 between 2 True sequence. I hope I am clear

Comment: @Ben I think it is the low pulse that needed remove

Comment: Please include _in the question text_ an actual example with logical values as well as your code

Comment: X = 111110011111000000011000011111  The condition is that if the number of zeros in-between ones is less than 3 seconds then the sequences are converted to 1. While if the sequence 1 in between two zeros is it is converted to zero.  The final solution is 11111111111100000000000011111X = [1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1];  % Work with this array.

target = 3;
ind = find(X < target);
disp(ind);
logInd = X < target;

Comment: @ Ben in summary any sequence of isolated 00 is converted to 11 while that of  isolated 11 is converted into 00

Comment: @Jonatino: I understand that, and I understand that your description is underspecified for `[0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1]`  Should the lone `0` be changed to a `1` or should the lone `1` be changed to a zero?  Maybe in that case you don't care.  Here are some more inputs for which the behavior is underspecified that I suspect you do care about the result: `[0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0]` and `[0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1]`

Comment: @Ben Thanks very much for that.  for the first example, you gave the lone zero becomes 1.  In your second example, the lone 1 becomes 0 and while in the third example the lone zeros becomes 1.  I hope that is clear.  Thanks in advance

Comment: @Jonatino Ok how about `[0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1]` This is the same as the first example (short positive pulse adjacent to short negative pulse) except now the pulse widths are not equal.  Or a different variation, where the positive pulse doesn't last as long: `[0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0]`  That could be a length-4 positive pulse with one glitch in it.  Or continuously low with two glitches.  For an especially difficult example, `[0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,X,X,X,X,X,X,X]` Do the "best" choices for the beginning depend on X (whether the system settles high or low at the end)?

Comment: Hi Ben thanks for getting back to me. For the first example the lone zeros becomes 1,1.  For the second @Ben in your current example the lone 1 becomes 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.  For the final example the one becomes zeros. The system is focus on the grouping of 1 mostly. Which is any lone zero surrounded by ones more than 3 in both side is 1. I hope this is clear Ben

Comment: @Ben please find my comment above

Comment: @Jonatino: I think your transformation is actually equivalent to finding the sample sequence that minimizes (1.00 * EDGES + 0.99 * FP + 0.98 * FN) where FN means a false low/negative and FP a false high/positive.  That provides the following behavior: Flipping two samples is better than having two edges.  Ties are broken by preferring to flip a zero to high ("correct a false negative") than making a one low.   It's reminding me of my thesis, but your case is constrained to binary which means that the Viterbi decoder algorithm will be optimal.

Comment: I may write up the matlab code for you after work just because this sounds like a really fun problem.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Ben. I will try that and get back. Thanks again

Comment: @Ben  I will appreciate the code if possible.  I await your kind response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is code implementing minimization of (1.00 * EDGES + 0.99 * FP + 0.98 * FN) where FN means a false low/negative and FP a false high/positive.

The implementation uses the Viterbi decoder approach originally designed for optimal decoding of convolutional codes in a noisy channel.  The convolutional coding is replaced by penalizing every 0->1 and 1->0 transition.

I've named some of the variables in accordance with the application to receiving messages through a noisy link.  `rxmsg` is before the processing takes place, `decode` is the result of the processing.

```
function [best, trellis] = optimize(rules, rxmsg)
    endpoints = repmat(struct('decode', [], 'cost', 0), 2, 1);
    trellis = repmat(endpoints, 1, numel(rxmsg));
    for i = 1:numel(rxmsg)
        % find lowest cost path ending in low (0)
        if endpoints(1).cost < endpoints(2).cost + rules.edgecost
            from = endpoints(1);
            transition = 0;
        else
            from = endpoints(2);
            transition = rules.edgecost;
        end
        lowcost = rules.falsepositivecost * (1 == rxmsg(i));
        next(1) = struct('decode', [from.decode, 0], 'cost', from.cost + transition + lowcost);
        
        % find lowest cost path ending in high (1)
        if endpoints(1).cost + rules.edgecost < endpoints(2).cost
            from = endpoints(1);
            transition = rules.edgecost;
        else
            from = endpoints(2);
            transition = 0;
        end
        highcost = rules.falsenegativecost * (0 == rxmsg(i));
        next(2) = struct('decode', [from.decode, 1], 'cost', from.cost + transition + highcost);
        
        % prepare for next step
        endpoints = next;
        trellis(:, i) = next;
    end
    
    if endpoints(1).cost < endpoints(2).cost
        best = endpoints(1);
    else
        best = endpoints(2);
    end
    best.rxmsg = rxmsg;
end
```

Example usage:

> ```
> >> rules = struct('edgecost', 1.00, 'falsenegativecost', 0.98, 'falsepositivecost', 0.99);
> >> [best, trellis] = optimize(rules, [1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1])
>
> best = 
>
>     decode: [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1]
>       cost: 5.9400
>      rxmsg: [1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1]
>
>
> trellis = 
>
> 2x30 struct array with fields:
>
>     decode
>     cost
> ```

I also made a visualizer to see what bits have been changed

[image]

```
function display_message_and_decode(rxmsg, decodemsg)
    same = struct('t', [], 'y', []);
    rejected = same;
    corrected = same;
    
    agreemask = (rxmsg == decodemsg);
    for i = 1:numel(agreemask)
        if i > 1
            if agreemask(i-1) && agreemask(i)
                same.t = [same.t, NaN, i-1, i-.9];
                same.y = [same.y, NaN, rxmsg(i-1), rxmsg(i)];
            else
                rejected.t = [rejected.t, NaN, i-1, i-.9];
                rejected.y = [rejected.y, NaN, rxmsg(i-1), rxmsg(i)];
                corrected.t = [corrected.t, NaN, i-1, i-.9];
                corrected.y = [corrected.y, NaN, decodemsg(i-1), decodemsg(i)];
            end
        end
        
        if agreemask(i)
            same.t = [same.t, NaN, i-.9, i];
            same.y = [same.y, NaN, rxmsg(i), rxmsg(i)];
        else
            rejected.t = [rejected.t, NaN, i-.9, i];
            rejected.y = [rejected.y, NaN, rxmsg(i), rxmsg(i)];
            corrected.t = [corrected.t, NaN, i-.9, i];
            corrected.y = [corrected.y, NaN, decodemsg(i), decodemsg(i)];
        end
    end
    
    handles = plot(same.t, same.y, 'k-', rejected.t, rejected.y, 'r-', corrected.t, corrected.y, 'g-', 'LineWidth', 1);
    set(handles(1), 'LineWidth', 4);
    set(gca, 'YLim', [-.2 1.2]);
end
```

Here are results from some of the test cases discussed in comments:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

- Note the last three generated different results than your clarifying comment suggested.  Here is a function that will calculate the cost for any proposed solution you think is a better outcome:

  ```
  function result = score(rules, rxmsg, decodemsg)
      result = rules.edgecost * sum(abs(diff(decodemsg))) ...
          + rules.falsenegativecost * sum(decodemsg & ~rxmsg) ...
          + rules.falsepositivecost * sum(rxmsg & ~decodemsg);
  end
  ```

Comment: Thanks I am grateful for your help.